# Show Data Value in Column Chart Google Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I have created a chart using google-visualization but unable to get the data value for the second column

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004', 1000, 400],
      ['2005', 1170, 460],
      ['2006', 660, 1120],
      ['2007', 1030, 540]
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1,{
                            calc: "stringify",
                            sourceColumn: 1,
                            type: "string",
                            role: "annotation"
                        },
                        2]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        hAxis: { title: 'Users', titleTextStyle: { color: 'red', fontSize: 16} },
        legend: { position: 'bottom', textStyle: { color: 'blue', fontSize: 16} }
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(view, options);
```

The data value comes for the sales but not to expense column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another annotation column to the view:

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: "stringify",
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: "string",
    role: "annotation"
}, 2, {
    calc: "stringify",
    sourceColumn: 2,
    type: "string",
    role: "annotation"
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

dataView.setColumns([{ calc: function (data, row) { return data.getFormattedValue(row, 0); }, type: 'string' }, 1,2]);

Comment: Could you format your answer as code, and explain it please? Code-only answers are best avoided because they don't serve to help others except to solve their specific problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take your time on learning how to properly format code. Some comments to the code (why it should be done this way) are appreciated aswell.